# Eclipse Luna won't load

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse won't load! I've been trying to fix this Eclipse starting issue.

I'm getting "Exit Code 13"

It may have started because I added a plugin file from:

http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-full-screen-mode

> The plugin is available from http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fullscreen/. Download the zip file. The zip file has the `cn.pande.eclipsex.fullscreen_<version>.jar` file. Copy that file inside the CodeWarrrior or Eclipseeclipse\plugins folder.

I uninstalled the plugin, and re-installed the current version of Eclipse Luna and jre-8u25-windows-i586

Comment: Exit code 13 normally means you are using a 32 bit JRE with a 64 bit Eclipse (or the other way round). They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Exit code 13 normally means you are using a 32 bit JRE with a 64 bit Eclipse (or the other way round). They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit. –  greg-449 Nov 18 at 7:30 "

I had to reinstall Eclipse and then reinstall the correct corresponding 64 bit JRE and then it worked!